# VMSS can be used as a Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have looked to **VMSS Scale Set** in Azure, but i wonder can that help to create a cluster of **Linux VMs Machine** that can scale out. 
But if i use it how can i configure each created machine in the scale set?

Because each new node in cluster showed be configured in specific way

Is that just duplication to avoid single point of failure? or can be used as cluster can be scale in case of work load.

i've tried to create one and tested it was working but i need to automated the process of configuring the new added nodes.

Answer (score 0):

there are some notes on how you can deploy apps and configure scale set VMs here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app/ 
- in general, if the VMs in a scale set need to be individually configured in a different way I'd recommend creating individual VMs in an availability set instead.